# Why doesn't gcc o warn when size of array is uninitialized in this code?

Tags: c, arrays, gcc, initialization, compiler-warnings

Okay, so this is a stripped down variant of a bug I had. The bug was that I initialized an array using a variable that wasn't initialized. Earlier I used a function to declare the number of elements using a function, but after a cleanup I forgot about it and moved all declarations to the top of the function.

I used the flags `-std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -O`, and usually gcc warns about values being used before they are uninitialized, but in this specific case it didn't. So, my question is:

Is this a bug in `gcc` *or* is it possible for `f(&n)` to post-initialize the array size in some weird way?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void f(int * x) {
  *x = 8;
}


int main(void) {

  int n;
  float a[n]; // Compiler should warn that n may contain garbage

  a[7] = 3.1415;
  printf("%f\n", a[7]);

  f(&n);  // Removing this causes the compiler warn as expected

  return 0;
}
```

EDIT: It may be [this gcc bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=18501)?

Comment: looks like a bug to me

Answer (score 1):

GCC is accepting `float a[n]` as a variable-length array.  It should, however, warn you that `n` contains garbage when it’s used.  Perhaps VLA initialization is getting rearranged in a way that makes that fact non-obvious to the code generator?  If `n` were initialized before use, moving the call to `f()` above the declaration of `a` would clearly be wrong, but this program produces undefined behavior.

Comment: How do you mean? I it's unclear; removing f(&n) from main causes the compiler to catch and warn that n is used uninitialized.

Comment: Yes, that definitely sounds like a compiler bug.  Suppose you’d initialized `int n = 1; float a[n]; f(&n);`.  In that case, the compiler clearly needs to update `n` after it allocates the VLA.  Some refactoring during the optimization phase is confusing it.